# Unable to query for lookup type's value in REST API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I have two lists: Categories and Courses. My Courses list has a column that is a lookup type. I use this so the view for the list will have a drop down that will let me pick the different categories from the Categories list. I named this lookup type column as 'Category'.

[image]

When I run my query to the REST API I get a 400 error and I do not understand why. I have looked all over the internet and tried many things that I have found yet nothing has worked.

Here is my query: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items$select=Category`

I have also tried using expand as I have seen all over the internet like so:
`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items$select=Category/CategoryID&$expand=Category/CategoryID`

and

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items$select=Category/CategoryID&$expand=Category`

but this gives the same 400 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little error. If the field's name is Category, your query should be:

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items$select=*,Category/ID&$expand=Category

Where Category is the LookUp internal name
[image]

In the image you can see that i have EncuestaId as a LookUpField on the list Respuestas, so my query is:

```
http://vmsps2013/sites/publicacion/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Respuestas')/items?$expand=Encuesta&$select=*,Encuesta/Id
```

Comment: I just gave that a shot without any luck. I changed it from 'Category/ID' to 'Category/CategoryID' since that is the name of the ID column in my Category list but I still get a 400 error. Any ideas?

Comment: the name of my list of lookup type that references the Categories list is called 'Category'. I didn't include any additional columns when I made this lookup type. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you please run your query just till items and check the internal name of the Category field? this should be CategotyId, you have to expand the column not the list.

Comment: I'm confused. Sorry pretty new to all of this. I went ahead and ran the query to get all items : '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items?$select=*' and the only fitting name I find is called CategoryNameId. I don't know how in the world that fits in any way. I had that name a long time ago but changed it. Shouldn't it match what I have?? Either way if I try adding that name to the query it still fails.

Comment: awesome, now expand CategoryName and select CategoryName/Id try that

Comment: That fails. My point is that I don't have a column named 'CategoryName'. The lookup column is named 'Category'.

Comment: Did you check the image that attach to the answer?

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the lists and recreated them since I was having old names pop up. After doing that and referencing what you have I was able to get it working. There was an inconsistency in the naming. Thank you!

Comment: your very welcome :)